# Lightning Component record ID when component in Lightning Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Ok, stupid question but I have searched and could not find this anywhere...

**Q:** How to you get (what is the expression syntax of) the ID of the record which is displaying the component / app?

I have read that I need to implement the interface <strike>`force:recordTab`</strike> here

> Q: How is Lightning aware of what record you are on if you embed it in
>   Salesforce1? (i.e. how do you get the ID of the record you are on like
>   in a standard controller)?
>
> A: Your component just needs to implement
>   the force:recordTab interface and the record and recordId will be
>   automatically injected when your component is wired into record home.

from the FAQ: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ

**Since found to be incorrect (see answer)**

but beyond that I could find no documentation on this interface or anything in the lightning component developer guide that discusses this.

Basically, on init I need to grab the ID of the record whose detail page is being displayed.

Sorry for the newbie question but you would think something this simple would be out there in the open.....

Comment: Can you do this on load of Lightning component and get Id in Controller constructor? I can pass it on button click and stuff. But can we get the id directly on load of page in constructor?

Comment: It is available as a merge variable anywhere in the component

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found it after doing some serious reading of the Winter '16 release.

You need to implement the interface:

```
force:hasRecordId
```

in your component and then you can access the record id via the following expression

```
{!v.recordId}
```

An example component would be:

```
<aura:component controller="CTRL_F_Controller" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
<aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account"/>
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/bootstrap"/>
    <div class="bootstrap-sf1">
       <div class="container">
           <ui:outputText class="form-control" aura:id="recid" value="{!v.recordId}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I guess this is available only in winter 16 ?Does it work in summer 15 as well?

Comment: I believe it is new for winter 16. Not sure how it is done in summer 15 or if it can be

Comment: It was not possible as straight as that :)..Thanks that we have and +1 from me on question and answer as well

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - Would be interested in how you did it in Winter 15. Please feel free to update my answer with the code used from Winter 15 to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you embedding this component in any record detail page ?

Comment: @Monish - Yes that was the goal

Comment: can you anwer thsi question please http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97130/navigating-to-custom-component-from-standard-opportunity-page-in-lightning-exper

Comment: Can you tell me how to embed the component in detail page.

Comment: @Monish - Sorry, not played that far yet....try passing the id as a url param and implementing the above

Comment: @Monish - you just drag it onto the page....

Comment: So I have tried replicating this to no success.  It don't think this is the answer.  Is there any other potential solution or requirements, to get the record ID.

Comment: @AndrewJackman - I can confirm it is still working as expected. Very simply create an app named CTRL_F and copy and paste the component (Remove the controller part) . The place it on the page layout and you will see that the ID is displayed.

Comment: @Eric One note I have left out is I am trying to do this on an SF communities page.  I have used almost exactly your example, only replacing `Account` for my custom object name.  I updated [my question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100211/how-to-access-record-id-in-custom-lightning-component) with the code I am using.

Comment: These two blogs (almost same) provide some details into this topic:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html

http://peterknolle.com/lightning-components-for-record-home-pages/