# How to access Record ID in custom lightning component in a Salesforce Community

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components

I tried following the question and answer to no success here: [Lightning Component record ID when component in Lightning Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93060/lightning-component-record-id-when-component-in-lightning-page)

How can I access the record ID from the URL in a custom lightning component?  My end goal is to create a styled object details component showing some of the information (instead of the default details component).

Here is the code I have used so far:

```
<aura:component controller="CommunityPost_Controller" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:recordTab">
    <aura:attribute name="Community_News_Item__c" type="Community_News_Item__c" />
    <ui:outputText class="form-control" aura:id="recid" value="{!v.recordId}" />
</aura:component>
```

And I am loading this off of a data detail page on a salesforce community with the Napili template enabled.

Comment: The answer in the related question still works and the id variable displays properly. Maybe you can post what you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally figured it out.  The `force:hasRecordId` is not available with Salesforce Communities.  To access the record Id from a data detail page, you need to do two things:

1. Create an aura attribute to hold the variable, and ensure you don't include a default value here
2. Create a design attribute with a default value of `{!recordId}`

And that will allow the system to pass the record ID to the component when it loads on the page.